# How to run Dartium on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dart, dartium

I am new to Dart and want to start developing apps for Dart. Right now, I am simply using `dart2js --minify` for this, which works well, but is really slow when I need to debug my mistakes by changing the code, running the code, changing the code, running the code, etc.. This requires lots of compiling, so while `dart2js` is, in general, pretty fast, debugging Dart Web apps with `dart2js` is really slow.

I would like to use the Dart VM in Dartium and downloaded it per the directions of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_0iMi1XpTE) (although admittedly, I didn't watch the whole video because part of it was about Atom which I don't use). However, when I open Dartium (`./chrome` and `./chrome-wrapper`), it doesn't look any different front regular Chrome. There is no `--no-sandbox` warning and the user agent is the same as in Chromium (no `(Dart)`). When I try to run a Dart Web app with `<script type="application/dart" [...]>`, it doesn't work.

I also get the following error when running Dartium (the same error occurs on `./chrome` and `./chrome-wrapper`):

```
[18997:18997:0829/163445:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(163)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Created new window in existing browser session.
[19044:19044:0829/163446:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(587)] write: Broken pipe
[0829/163446:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(282)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

However, when I go to [the link in the error](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment), the directions refer to a bunch of commands and files I don't recognize.

Can someone please help me figure out how to build Dartium? Thank you so much!

Additional Info:

- I am running Ubuntu 15.04 and my default browser is Chromium.
- When I ran both `./chrome` and `./chrome-wrapper`, I had my original Chromium closed.
- I have uploaded my project [to GitHub](https://github.com/Noble-Mushtak/Miscellaneous/tree/master/Dart).

Comment: I get the same error message when I start Dartium from command line without arguments. I usually start Dartium from WebStorm and there such messages aren't visible but I also never had issues which seem related to this error. See my answer for more information. If you still can't make it work, please provide more information about your project (`pubspec.yaml`, directory structure, source file content)

Comment: If you want to see my project, you can go [here](https://github.com/Noble-Mushtak/Miscellaneous/tree/master/Dart).

Comment: I took a brief look and all seems fine. Seeing you accepted my project I assume you got it working. Don't hesitate to ask if you're stuck again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Dartium is connecting to an existing version of Chromium. Try to launch Dartium with `--user-data-dir=/tmp/dartium_dir`. This will make sure that it launches separately from any existing Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way to check if you run Dartium is to enter `about://version` in the URL bar and check if `Dart: someversion` is listed. I usually start Dartium from WebStorm which lists the following command line in `about://version`

> /usr/local/apps/dart/dartium/chrome --no-sandbox --flag-switches-begin --disable-async-dns --enable-devtools-experiments --enable-download-resumption --javascript-harmony --enable-panels --flag-switches-end

Instead of `dart2js` it's usually simpler to use `pub build`. `pub build` is usually used for deployment only. For development it usually works best to run the Dart development web server `pub serve`. Pub serve builds to JavaScript on the fly when a non-Dart-capable browser requests a page. If Dartium requests a page it serves the Dart source code instead. If your source changes you automatically get the updates JS when you reload the page in a non-Dart-capable browser.

(if you change dependencies with `pub get` or `pub upgrade` you need to restart `pub serve`)

Comment: Thank you for telling me about `pub serve`! It's working quite well for me right now! However, I would prefer to have Dartium if possible. I tried the command line arguments you gave me and nothing changed. Even though I specified `--no-sandbox` like in your command line arguments, there was no `--no-sandbox` warning. I also checked out [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/), but it looks like it's only a 30-day trial before I have to buy it and I don't want to use another IDE just for Dart. Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I saw Dartium produces the same error message as in your question when I launch it from command line. This doesn't seem to cause any further issues though.

Comment: You can use `pub serve` with Dartium as well. `pub serve` serves the original Dart source to Dartium and generated JS to other browsers automatically. IntelliJ is quite similar to WebStorm where a community edition is available if this is of any help. Some frameworks (like Polymer.dart and Angular.dart and probably) require `pub serve`. They use transformers which generate some Dart code on-the-fly and some things don't work when the transformers are not applied (`pub build` also applies these transformers before generating JS). Using `pub serve` during development is usually a good idea.

Comment: When I tried to open Dartium with `pub serve`, it worked just like on Chrome, but without the `packages/browser/dart.js` script, it didn't work because for some reason, it wasn't able to run `application/dart` scripts with the Dart VM. However, I'll look into IntelliJ since that might work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Weird, only non-Dartium browsers require the `packages/browser/dart.js` script.

Comment: It looks like all I needed was the `--user-data-dir=/tmp/dartium_dir` flag. Then, I went to `chrome://version` and it listed `--user-data-dir=/tmp/dartium_dir --no-sandbox --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end` as the command line arguments.